# How to draw line out of drawrect function  on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-graphics

need to draw line touchBegan, touchMove function instead of drawRect function on class derivated from  UIView Subclass

Answer (score 2):

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007300) does an excellent job of introducing all the concepts and details you'll need. Please read first, and ask specific questions if you have trouble understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass a UIView.  Implement a drawRect in that custom subclass.  Call setNeedsDisplay on a visible instance of that class.  Use CG or Core Graphics commands to stroke a path.  See Apple's Core Graphics reference documents on developer.apple.com.